# Netbeans zf2 run configs

Tags: zend-framework2, config

Im setting up a ZF2 project on netbeans 7.4. pressing run project showed just folder like that instead of running straight to public . teach me how. thank you all

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add some plugins to your netbeans

- http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46432/php-zend-framework-2
- http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51969/netbeans-zf2-module-creator

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run and debug a web site, you first need to edit the
site's properties. To do that, in NetBeans' *Projects* pane, right-click
on the project's name, and from context menu select *Properties* item.
The project's *Properties* dialog will appear (shown in figure below).

[image: Properties | Sources]

In the left pane of the dialog that appears, click the *Sources* node. In the right pane, 
edit the *Web Root* field to point to your web site's `APP_DIR/public` directory. 
You can do this by clicking the *Browse* button to the right of the field. Then,
in the dialog, click on the *public* directory and then click *Select Folder* button
(shown in figure below).

[image: Browse Folders Dialog]

Next, click the *Run Configuration* node in the left pane. The right pane should display
the run settings for your site (see figure below).

[image: Properties | Run Configuration]

In the right pane, you can see that the current configuration is "default". As an option, you can 
create several run configurations.

Edit the fields as follows:

- In the *Run As* field, select "Local Website (running on local web server)".
- In the *Project URL* field, enter `http://localhost`. If you configured your virtual
  host to listen on different port (say, on port 8080), enter the port number like this `http://localhost:8080`.
- Keep the *Index File* field empty, because Apache's `mod_rewrite` module will mask
  our actual *index.php* file.
- In the *Arguments* field, you can specify which GET parameters to pass to your site through 
  the URL string. Typically, you keep this field empty.

Finally, click the *OK* button to close the *Properties* dialog.

### Running the Web Site

Running the web site means opening it in your default web browser. To launch
the site, press the *Run* button on the *Run Toolbar* (see figure below). Alternatively, 
you can press *F6* button on your keyboard.

[image: Run Toolbar]

If everything is OK with your run configuration, the default web browser
will be launched, and in the browser window, you will be able to see the *Home* page of
the web site.

For additional information about using NetBeans with ZF2, I would recommend you to read the [Using Zend Framework 2](http://using-zend-framework-2-book.com) book.